# Convert an ArrayList of object to String without having the quote character " " at the start and at the end of this string in CVS file

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, tostring, stringbuilder

I try to write value from an ArrayList of object (Dico) in CSV file with [apache commons CSV](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/).

The problem is when I convert my Dico object to string with StringBuilder the quote char are at the start and at the end, I need to remove it before writing in CSV file.

This is the Dico class that I try to save weight in CSV file

```
public class Dico  
{ private String m_term; private double m_weight; private int m_Id_doc; }

public String toString() 
{  return String.valueOf(this.getWeight());  }
```

This is a function that I use to convert from an ArrayList of Dico to String:

```
// construct new string from weigth of eche term in vector
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();    
// vector is List<Dico>           
vector.stream().forEach((str) -> {  sb.append(str).append(","); });
```

To write this data in cvs file with apache commons CSV line by line i use a loop iterate over List> get weight of each dico from List and save it in string .

> ```
>    //initialize FileWriter object  
>    fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileName);  
>    csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);//initialize CSVPrinter object       
>    csvFilePrinter.printRecord(FILE_HEADER); //Create CSV file header
>
>     for (List list_id:sublists) //Write a each node list by id to the CSV file
>
>          {
>             vector= weight_term(list_id,sinficatif);
>             List DataRecord = new ArrayList();
>             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();// construct new string from weigth of eche term in vector
>             String value= null; 
>             List<String> weights = new ArrayList<> ();
>
>      for(Dico str: vector)
>           {  
>                sb.append(str).append(","); 
>                value = sb.substring(0, sb.length()-1).toString();
>          }
>
>           DataRecord.add(String.valueOf(vector.get(0).getDocId()));// id of list 
>             DataRecord.add(value);
>             csvFilePrinter.printRecord(DataRecord);
>             }
> ```

### Result:

The input are `[1 , foo , 1.5 , 1 , bar , 1.15 , 1 , glu , 0.0]`.

The output in CSV file are `1,"1.5,1.15,0.0"`.

I want this:`1,1.5,1.15,0.0`

How can I save it without " " , I have also same result when I use the method `toString` to convert the array Vector to string .

### Note:

the quote char are added **automatically** !

Comment: Instead of using stream().forEach(), take a look at String.join() method

Comment: CVS is an outdated source-code version control system. CSV is "Comma-Separated Values", a way to store columnar data. I'm assuming the latter so I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Comment: `apache commons CSV` have a `Enum QuoteMode Class` maybe this can help you. [class description](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/index.html) - [use](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/apidocs/org/apache/commons/csv/class-use/QuoteMode.html)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `toString()` method to get the value you need, why not just use `getWeight()`?

Comment: if you read my question you will see : "I have also same result when I use the method toString to convert this array."

Comment: That is exactly why I suggest that you DO NOT use the toString method, but use the getWeight method directly.

Comment: the probleme comes from apache commons cvs not from getWeight or toString

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the code that writes the CSV file.

The way that you're writing now, it's not possible to remove the double quotes. What you are doing is writing a single column with the values `1.5,1.15,0.0,`.

Because there are comma's in the value, Apache-commons-csv *needs* to escape the comma's by quoting the string. If it didn't, the single value would turn into multiple values when the CSV file is read.

I assume that this is what you actually want - to write multiple values.

With apache-commons-csv, the library takes care of that. Don't write a single value; instead write multiple values and the library will take care of placing comma's between them.

```
CSVPrinter csvFilePrinter = new CSVPrinter(fileWriter, csvFileFormat);
List<String> weights = ...; // Your weights
csvFilePrinter.printRecord(weights);
```

Comment: To be more clear i have a `List<List<Dico> >`  where each `List <dico>` represent document with diffrent id i nedd to store weight of term form list in the same line of cvs file.
I try to make this:    `id,w1,w2,w3..........,wn`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `substring()` method to return only a section of the `String`, in this case you need all characters except for the first and last.

```
sb.substring(1, sb.length()-1);
```

Where `sb` is your `StringBuilder` object.

Comment: its does not work the quote are not considerate as a parte of string, whene i use `sb.substring(1, sb.length()-1);` the output are : ".5,1.15,0.0"

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my answer is too late, but hopefully it will help someone when strugling with this issue.

When creating the CSVFormat instance make sure that you define the header as well.

`CSVFormat csvFileFormat = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withHeader("COLUMN1", "COLUMN2", "COLUMN3");`

and later, when you `csvFilePrinter.printRecords(ob1, ob2, ob3)` then you won't have the quotes at the start and end of the line.